# javascript crashing when load array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problem when this function load resulting a crash in browser, when the calculation gives a long result.

when return payments is > 2000 it crash

```
function getPayments (minimumPayment, originalBalance, interestRate) {

    var balance = document.getElementById("balance").value;
    const payments = [];
    while(1) {
        let balance = originalBalance / 1;
        let payment = minimumPayment * balance / 100;
        if (payment < 10) payment = 10;
        const interest = ((interestRate / 12) * balance / 100);
        const principal = payment - interest;

        //alert(principal;
        balance -= principal;

        payments.push({
            payment: +payment.toFixed(2),
            principal: +principal.toFixed(2),
            balance: +balance.toFixed(2)
        })
        originalBalance = balance;

        if(interest <= 0) break;
    }
    console.log(payments);

    return payments;
}
```

Comment: Can you try doing the functions in a web worker in the background. Just search for web workers in Mozilla JavaScript documentation to use it

Comment: Can  you give the minimumPayment, originalBalance, interestRate that are making it crash the browser?

Comment: ... and `balance`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have encountered and infinite loop. You trying to break the loop when interest goes below and your code does not seem to do that